# Laravel - How to allow routes parameters with slash?

Tags: laravel

I detect a problem in my laravel route that receive 3 parameters but the parameters could have `/`. For example: in this route: `Route::get('/checkSerial/{brand}/{model}/{serie}', 'CORController@checkSerial')`

If the brand value was this: irc/12234 it will assume that exists 4 parameters and not.

I check in documentation to handle it in this way `Route::get('/checkSerial/{brand}/{model}/{serie}', 'CORController@checkSerial')->where(['brand' => '[/]+', 'model' => '[/]+', 'serie' => '[/]+']);`

but doesn't work .

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 3):

The regular expression you want is this `[a-zA-Z0-9\-\/]+`.
In your `where` clause   using only  `[\]+` you tell laravel that you parameter is only combination of `\` . 
Thus you need combination of letters `a-zA-Z` numbers`0-9` and `\`.

Still i'm not sure if  laravel can parse wildcards with `/`. Just try it !!!

---

Answer (score 3):

Your regular expression is wrong.

Use :

```
Route::get('/checkSerial/{brand}/{model}/{serie}','CORController@checkSerial')
    ->where(['brand' => "[\w\/]+"]);
```

This means that the brand is allowed to have word characters and slashes.

However if your model and serie also need to support a slash then you have a problem. Consider:

```
checkSerial/irc/12234/12/3/5
```

All the following work:

> brand = irc/12234 model = 12/3 serie = 5
>
> brand = irc model = 12234/12 serie = 3/5
>
> brand = irc/12234 model = 12 serie = 3/5

and so on, so be very careful how you define this.